# Is mongorestore.exe file present in mongo 4.4?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-tools

**Is mongorestore.exe file present in mongo 4.4 community edition?** If not, how is the restoration done in mongo 4.4?

Comment: From 4.4 mongodb releasing both separately [see](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/#versioning) (mongodb tools), you can download from here https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/), its moved under tools.

> MONGORESTORE DOCUMENTATION MIGRATED TO MONGODB DATABASE TOOLS
> Starting in MongoDB 4.4, the documentation for mongorestore has migrated to:
>
> https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore

You can install separately.

Comment: I can't find it there.